# Laravel aggregate function within single query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a User model with a table as users(id, email, password, gender, status)

I want to list the users based on condition along with the gender counts, here is my code:

```
$users = App\User::where('status', '1');
$users = $users->orderBy('email');

$data['all_users'] = $users; // all users
$data['total_males'] = $users->where('gender', 'M')->count(); // male count
$data['total_females'] = $users->where('gender', 'F')->count(); // female count

return view('users.list', $data);
```

The above code does not returns all the users on the view and filters gender, even when I have already passed the result object $users to the $data array.

Off course, I can set a male_count and female_count variables on the view and increment it based on the conditions like if (gender == 'M') total_males++ and display out of the loop.

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you add error or more description it's difficult to understand the problem

Comment: you have to add `->get()` on `$users` to get the data, you are just adding `$users` at all users

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do your eloquent queries on your controller and pass the data to the view would be:

```
$users = App\User::where('status', '1')->orderBy('email')->get();

$data['all_users'] = $users; // all users
$data['total_males'] = App\User::where('gender', 'M')->count(); // male count
$data['total_females'] = App\User::where('gender', 'F')->count(); // female count

return view('users.list', $data);
```

Comment: Seriously,  `->get()` is not required I think count should work.

Comment: Yep based on Laravel's doc, no need to add get. https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#aggregates

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple thing, that I forgot! I have a habit of putting get() function on the view: :p

```
$data['all_users'] = $users->get(); // all users
$data['total_males'] = $users->where('gender', 'M')->count(); // male count
$data['total_females'] = $users->where('gender', 'F')->count(); // female count
```

Comment: what do you mean by _on the view_ ?

Comment: @BenjaminBrasseur on the blade view. ;)

Comment: Oh ok. That's a bit strange of calling the request in the view instead of the controller ^^ So know, everything is working if you do the get on `$users` ?

Comment: Don't run eloquent queries or modify data on a view, do it on the controller. Please :'(

Answer (score 0):

You didn't called `get` method. Please try

```
$data['all_users'] = $users->get(); // all users
```

Answer (score -2):

The Eloquent didn't execute, because nothing get or count method in there
$data['all_users'] = $users->count(); // all users

Comment: Please explain a little bit more your answer. Don't just give code without explaining why.

Comment: just explain what you want to say .